# Could not run function which includes setTimeout() twice. Strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a problem with javascript functions **setTimeout()** and **setInterval()** functions.

Basicly my function handles form submit action. After clicking "submit" button all data from pointed *form* is serialized and send through ajax which fires "*functionName*". *functionName* returns *1* if everything is OK or *error code* if not. After that popup div is created with *successful message* or *error code*. Popup div should be visible for 6 seconds. User should see countdown from *6* to *0*. When zero is reached the page is redirected if redirection argument is given. if redirection argument is not given popup div is removed. I'm using ***setTimeout()*** function which couses some troubles. before that I was using *setinterval* function and the problem looked almost the same.

When funcion *handleSubmit* is fired for the first time (submit buttin is clicked)  the countdown function works great, but when I fire this function again the strage things happen. I use *onclick* to run my function.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="handleSubmit('formName', 'functionName', 'redirectURL')" value="send" />
```

Here is the definition of my function:

```
function handleSubmit(formName, functionName, redirectLocation){
    $('form#' + formName).submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/functions/module=none,method=' + functionName,
            data: $('form#' + formName).serialize(),
            success: function(data){

                var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('messages');
                div.appendTo('.content_block');

                var exitButton = $('<p class="title" style="overflow: hidden; margin-top:10px;"></p>');

                /**
                  * If the redirectLocation argument is empty we create HTML button with
                  * removeElement function which removes HTML popup DIV with class "messages"
                  * but if redirectLocation argument is provided we create HTML button with
                  * redirect function so after clicking we will be redirected.
                  * This buttons are created if we dont want to wait 6 seconds
                  */ 

                if(redirectLocation=='')
                    var button = $('<img title="Close this message" onclick="removeElement(\'.messages\')" src="/public/images/close.png" alt="Close message" style="cursor: pointer; float: right; padding-right: 10px;" width="16" height="16"  />');
                else
                    var button = $('<img title="Close this message" onclick="redirect(\''+ redirectLocation + '\')" src="/public/images/close.png" alt="Wyłącz komunikat" style="cursor: pointer; float: right; padding-right: 10px;" width="16" height="16"  />');


                exitButton.html(button);
                div.html(exitButton);
                var message = $('<p></p>');

              /**
                * Data recieved from AJAX 
                */

                if(data==1){

                    message.html("Data was successful uploaded");
                    message.appendTo(div);

                    var timer = $('<span id="timer"></span>');
                    timer.html('Message will be closed after: <b id="show-time">6</b> sec.');
                    timer.appendTo(div);

                    setTimeout("timedCount(" + redirectLocation + ")", 1000);                //this is countdown function

                }else{
                    message.html("Error: " + functionName + ".");
                    var error = $('<p>Error content: ' + data + '</p>');
                    error.appendTo(message);
                    message.appendTo(div);

                    var timer = $('<span id="timer"></span>');
                    timer.html('Message will be closed after: <b id="show-time">6</b> sek.');
                    timer.appendTo(div);
                    setTimeout("timedCount(" + redirectLocation + ")", 1000);                //this is countdown function
                }

                return true;
            }});
    });

}
```

And my timedCount function which should counts down from 6 to 0 looks like this.

```
  function timedCount(redirectLocation){
    timeCounter = $('#show-time').html();
    updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter)- 1;
    $("#show-time").html(updateTime);
    t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
    if(updateTime == 0){
        if(redirectLocation){
            $('#timer').html('Redirecting...');
            window.location = (redirectLocation);
        }else{
            $('.messages').remove();
            clearTimeout(t);  
        }

    }
}
```

SUMMARY. First time (when not using *redirectLocation*) function *hendleSubmit* works fine. But when the submit button is clicked second time, my *timedCount* function isn't counting down from 6 to 0 and *setTimeout* runs in background for eternity.
I have no idea what causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the `submit` event handler for the form inside of the `click` event handler for the submit-button. This means that on each subsequent click of the submit-button, another event handler is added for the `submit` event for the form.

How about declaring the `submit` event handler for **all** forms in a more global space? Just move `$('form#' + formName).submit(function(event){...})` outside the `handleSubmit` function: `$('form').submit(function(event){...})`.

Also you should use an anonymous function in your `setTimeout` declarations (this will avoid using `eval()` when it is not necessary):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    timedCount(redirectLocation)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @user1118341 I'm glad to have helped. And welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to enter new line and the comment was sent. Using your suggesions I moved `$('form').submit(function(event){...})` outside handleSubmit function and removed onclick event. Two arguments for _functionName_ and _redirectLocation_ were put in `<input type="hidden" (...)` elements and catch using $('#element_name').val();. Also I declare anonymous function for setTimeout. I'm new here so how can I give you a feedback?